# jQuery intermittent .on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm building a web app using django and jQuery and on one of the pages the $(document).com('click'... event fires very intermittently.  I have a list of items in a checkout queue, and an option to delete each item.  If I go from top to the bottom of the list, the click events mostly fire (but not always).  If I start from the bottom, sometimes they fire, sometimes not.  Some need 2 clicks, some need 6+ clicks before registering.

Onto the code.  This is the html django generates from the template:

```
<div class="container">
    <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:70%">Product</th>
                            <th style="width:10%" class="text-center">Seller</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
                            <th style="width:10%"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr  id="product-3653672818">
                            <td data-th="Product">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><img src="xyz.com/img.jpg" style="width: 121px; height: 88px;"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h4 class="nomargin">Product Name</h4>
                                        <p>Product Description</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-th="Seller" class="text-center">ONLINE</td>
                            <td data-th="Price">3.00</td>
                            <td class="actions" data-th="">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o DeleteItem" id="3653672818"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr  id="product-3653492642">
                            <td data-th="Product">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><img src="xyz.com/img.jpg" style="width: 121px; height: 88px;"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <h4 class="nomargin">Product #2 Title</h4>
                                        <p>Product #2 Description</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-th="Seller" class="text-center">ONLINE</td>
                            <td data-th="Price">4.00</td>
                            <td class="actions" data-th="">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o DeleteItem" id="3653492642"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.DeleteItem',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var thisID = $(this).attr("id");
    var data = { Action: "delete", itemid: thisID};

    var pr = "#product-"+thisID;
    $(pr).fadeOut(500, function() { $(pr).remove(); });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/cart/", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: data, 
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        },

        // handle a successful response
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.result == "OK") {
                console.log(json); 
                console.log("success"); 
            } else {
                console.log(json); 
                console.log("failure"); 
            }
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Just in case anybody else encounters this situation, I eventually worked out what was going on here.

The way I defined the button in the template was the culprit:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o DeleteItem" id="3653672818"></i></button>
```

My jQuery was firing on $(document).on('click','.DeleteItem' which was a class defined in the "i" html element, rather than the main button class.  The "fa-trash-o" class is a small trash can icon which only takes up about 1/3 of the button area.

So what would happen is if you clicked smack bang in the middle of the button (directly on the trash can), everything would work.  But if you clicked elsewhere on the button, nothing happened. ie. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

The fix was to move the "DeleteItem" class definition to the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm DeleteItem" id="3653672818"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i></button>
```

Comment: Wow, I am so glad I found your post. I would have spent ages working it out. Even after I read it I thought it couldn't possibly be the reason, but it was!